# Communicating With ASP.net Form Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net

I am interested in creating a Java grade portal for a school system, but I'm having a problem posting the data in the ASP.net form. I have redirected the data to my own form and the data is submitted, but for some reason, the post data will not work on the grade service itself. I have submitted the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION in the application, but it redirects back to the login page with no data submitted. One time though, an ASP.net error appeared.

```
//Post Data
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://loudoun.gradebook.net/clarity/Gradebook/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fclarity%2fGradebook%2f");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Username", username.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$Password", password.getText().toString()));

//ASP Net Values
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTVALIDATION", "/wEWBgKO4ofwAwLnksmgAQKTpbWbDgLB5+KIBAL4xb20BAK20ZqiCS7btK5SrOdsZpByJbSl/e54HnFG"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", "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"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

System.out.println(responseText);
```

Of course, I cannot supply a username and password for you to test (against county policy), but perhaps I can get relative information as to why it isn't working correctly.

Comment: Is there any information logged/reported on the server which indicates why the request failed?  I imagine the `__EVENTVALIDATION` and/or `__VIEWSTATE` values may change with each request, in part to prevent exactly what you're attempting.  You may need to request the page first, parse out those values from the response, and include the parsed values in your POST request.

Comment: David's on the right track - it's a security measure that prevents an external application from "mimicing" a `Postback` which is the mechanism in ASP.Net WebForms. Depending on how much more validation occurs on the ASP.Net application, you may not be able to accomplish what you are trying to do. [This summarizes things in quick read fashion](http://madskristensen.net/post/Secure-your-forms-in-ASPNET) - old but gives the basic idea, with links to MSDN. Doesn't the "grade service" (I'm assuming that's the service) have a different API?

Comment: I've looked into it more, and discovered that you're correct about the Event Validation changing. Perhaps I'll look into the API and work with that for a bit.